# get request, the same parameters are sent but the result varies

Tags: python

I am trying to use the web request of this page:

[image]

(click on the menu on the right where it says "word" and write a word in the text box, for example "vi")

the web request is done like this (This is what I can see from the element inspector in the web console.):

[image]

this is the response:

[image]

When trying to perform the same process and get the same process from postman, I get a different response. Why?

How can I get the same answer from a program or language that allows web requests?

[image]

Comment: How would we (random people on the internet) know why that service is behaving the way it is?

Comment: @HereticMonkey http://cartago.lllf.uam.es/grampal/grampal.cgi?m=analiza&csrf=6f7d39c3490b7088bda2583d4ed0eeaf&e=analiza precisely is the reason for the construction of this question. it works with a good result in a browser, but not in a web request through some programming language. You can access that link and you will see a different answer in your browser and another in the web petition. (you can see my screenshots)

Comment: a) I'm not going to click on links to random websites. b) The programmers of the website probably don't want you to make requests through a programming language; are you sure you're not violating the Terms of Service? Again, how would we know how that website is programmed?

Comment: @HereticMonkey a) it is not a random website, it is a site that I have searched and studied. It consists of writing a word and it is returned through a web service its stemming. b) it seems to be a site of a community of the Spanish language for the public (same, I sent an email to corroborate it). c) I have no idea how the website is made, nor what should be sent in the petition, I simply see what is sent when consuming the web request and doing the same I hope to get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page has a meta tag with the authors email address

```
<meta name="author" content="jmguirao@ugr.es">
```

I'd recommend you to contact him to inquire about usage of the 'API'.

But in general, you should be able to send an empty postmen request to http://cartago.lllf.uam.es/grampal/grampal.cgi

Then you have to parse the result and extract the value of the hidden input field named "csrf"

Then you can use this value to send further requests with the actual words you want to search.

How many requests, or how long time you can use a csrf value for, is information that you can get from the author of  the page.  (Or by trial and error I guess)

If you use the service irresponsibly, you are most likely going to be blocked.